# WPF: Pass Click to all overlaying/stacked Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-bubbling, stacked

Lets say I have Control A and Control B.

Control B is stacked in A.

```
<ControlA posX="0" popsY="0">
   <ControlB posX="0" popsY="0"/>
</ControlA>
```

How can I achieve that a click event is handled from both Controls?
I'm using MVVM.

Comment: What kind of controls are A and B?

Comment: I have treeViewItem and want to select it when a listbox item is clicked. the listbox is part of the hierachicalTemplate of the treeViewItem .

Comment: Well, please include a reproducible sample of your issue then instead of referring to something called ControlA and ControlB: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just want to know how i stop wpf from setting e.handled to true when a controls handles a event...so that other controls in visual tree still getting the event

Comment: That's not what you have asked.

Comment: Then it was badly expressed. Now you know :D